# Dynamic object keys in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a problem when setting the type of a dynamic object in TypeScript because the object that i create has dynamic keys and **three that are not**.

Here’s how i defined the type for the object:

```
interface GraphReturns {
 [key: string]: {
    ‘%’: number,
    value: number,
   ‘%Acumulated’: number
  },
  total: number,
  ‘total_%’: number,
  date: string
}
```

The errors i get:

1. Property ‘total’ of type ‘number’ is not assignable to ‘string’ index type ‘{ ‘%’: number; value: number; ‘%Acumulated’: number; }’
2. Property ‘‘total_%’’ of type ‘number’ is not assignable to ‘string’ index type ‘{ ‘%’: number; value: number; ‘%Acumulated’: number; }’
3. Property ‘date’ of type ‘string’ is not assignable to ‘string’ index type ‘{ ‘%’: number; value: number; ‘%Acumulated’: number; }’
   How can i fix this? Thank you!

Comment: can you show some examples of valid and invalid objects based on the desired type? Are the `"%"` here placeholders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see only two solutions here.

This one is seemed to be more "correct", but I'm not sure you can use it

```js
interface CallItSomehow {
    '%': number;
    value: number;
    '%Acumulated': number;
}

interface GraphReturns {
    total: number,
    'total_%': number,
    date: string
    other: Record<string, CallItSomehow>, // In this case you had to write information into another field
}
```

Or you can do

```
interface GraphReturns {
    total: number,
    'total_%': number,
    date: string
    [key: string]: {
        '%': number,
        value: number,
        '%Acumulated': number
    } | string | number,
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDyz1m) should be allowed...

Comment: Yes, that's why I called the first one is more correct)